# How to return the actual data from within a timeout instead of the timeout promise

Tags: angularjs, promise, timeout

I'm trying to return data from a function but I need a timeout in order to wait for some data to be set before doing some actions. However I can't figure out the most vital piece.

How can I return `'A string'` from `myFunc` instead of the `$timeout` promise?

```
function myFunc() {

  return $timeout(function() {

    return 'A string';
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could access `A string` waiting for the promise to resolve

```
myFunc().then(function(data){
    console.log(data); // 'A string'
});
```